# How to create grouped barchart in R from a table with multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a following data frame

```
proba <- data.frame(PartnerName = c("China", "Brazil", "Argentina", "UE", "US"), Food = c(1,2,3,4,5), Machinery = c(1,2,3,4,5), Chemicals = c(1,2,3,4,5), CrudeMaterials = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Now I would like to create a grouped bar chart which on the axis x shows the categories (Machinery, Food etc.) and on the axis y it shows the total value of grouped trade by country.

The chart I would like to get looks like this (I did it in excel):
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg9UY.png)

I can get a simple chart using barplot but it is not as detailed and accurate.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Easier to plot when the data is in long format. Try -

```
library(tidyverse)

proba %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -PartnerName, names_to = 'Category') %>%
  ggplot(aes(Category, value, fill = PartnerName)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: I was misled by the title 'grouped' barchart. I leave my answer if it is ok for you. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is a grouped bar chart getting with `position="dodge"` change it to `geom_col(position= "stack")` and you get the same as Ronak Shah:

```
proba %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        -PartnerName,
        names_to = "names",
        values_to = "values"
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=names, y=values, fill = PartnerName))+
    geom_col(position= "dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `gather`

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
proba %>% 
    gather(names, values, -PartnerName) %>%  
    ggplot(aes(x=names, y=values, fill = PartnerName))+
       geom_col()
```